# How to export users in Oracle with its roles and system privileges using expdp?

Tags: oracle, impdp, expdp, oracle-dump

I am trying to export a schema/user in Oracle with its roles and system privileges. I don't want to export any data or any table. I have tried to export users using the following command.

```
expdp system/system@gisdblocal include=user DIRECTORY = TestBack  
logfile=test12.log DUMPFILE=test12.dmp SCHEMAS=test_replication
```

When I import this in other database or in the same database with a different name i.e

```
impdp system/system@gisdblocal DIRECTORY = TestBack  DUMPFILE = test12.dmp   
SCHEMAS = test_replication REMAP_SCHEMA = 
test_replication:test_replication_copy
```

the user or schema is created but it has not been granted any role or system privileges.

I am doing this because I have created a backup of a schema using the user that did not have the required rights **DATAPUMP_IMP_FULL_DATABASE** or **DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE**. When I restore that backup in another database, it says the user does not exist. Therefore, I am thinking to create a user with the same privileges first and then restore the backup.

Comment: User creation and privilege granting are really the kind of thing which should be scripted and stashed in a source control repository.

Comment: What I do when I'm refreshing an entire schema from one DB to another, is drop all of the target schema objects, but not the user, prior to the import.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using SQL...

```
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('USER', :name)
  FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl('ROLE_GRANT', grantee)
  FROM dba_role_privs
 WHERE grantee = :name
   AND ROWNUM = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl('DEFAULT_ROLE', grantee)
  FROM dba_role_privs
 WHERE grantee = :name
   AND ROWNUM = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl('SYSTEM_GRANT', grantee)
  FROM dba_sys_privs          sp,
       system_privilege_map   spm
 WHERE sp.grantee = :name
   AND sp.privilege = spm.name
   AND spm.property <> 1
   AND ROWNUM = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl('OBJECT_GRANT', grantee)
  FROM dba_tab_privs
 WHERE grantee = :name
   AND ROWNUM = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl('TABLESPACE_QUOTA', username)
  FROM dba_ts_quotas
 WHERE username = :name
   AND ROWNUM = 1
```

:name being...a bind variable for the USER you want to re-create.

Comment: I have been an Oracle DBA since Version 5 of the database (mid-1980's).  This is the most clever way to get user information from database-to-database I have seen.  Wow. 
 Nice job.  And thanks for sharing.

Comment: it's the SQL we use behind the covers when using SQL Developer to manage users in the DBA > Security panel

Answer (score 0):

I found that some user privileges in dba_tab_privs but not in the above SQL results.

The default value of parameter OBJECT_COUNT is 10,000.

reset object_count=>3000000 get all the rows.

```sql
set longchunksize 3000  
set long 2000000000   
set lines 1000 
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_GRANTED_DDL('OBJECT_GRANT',GRANTEE, object_count=>3000000)
FROM dba_tab_privs;
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally use the below, (replace XXXXX with your username)

`set feedback off pages 0 long 90000 serveroutput on`

`SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('USER',username) from DBA_USERS where username='XXXXX';`

`SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_GRANTED_DDL('SYSTEM_GRANT',grantee) from DBA_SYS_PRIVS where grantee='XXXXX';`

`SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_GRANTED_DDL('ROLE_GRANT',grantee) from DBA_ROLE_PRIVS where grantee='XXXXX';`

`SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_GRANTED_DDL('OBJECT_GRANT',grantee) from DBA_TAB_PRIVS where grantee='XXXXX';`

Hope it helps for you !!